# How to use ObservableCollection with better way with using AsyncNetwork on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms.
It works great.

But the problem is most time works fine but sometimes crash. 
One of the clue that I guess is that the way I'm using ObservableCollection is wrong.
When I use it with background thread, I should use it carefully, shouldn't I?

I wrote different types below.
Please let me know what's the best way to use it.

Option 2 is correct way to use it? (And should?)
(I'm asking for the case when I have to call async method or anonymous method)

Thanks.

## Option 1 (I've been using this)

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            ImObservableCollection.Add(something);
        }
    }
}
```

## Option 2

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ImObservableCollection.Add(something));
        }
    }
}
```

## Option 3

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            ImObservableCollection.Add(something);
        }
    }
}
```

## Option 4

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    getsomething();
}

void async getsomething()
{
    var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        ImObservableCollection.Add(something);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the stack trace from the crash say? Please add it to your post. Otherwise, it'll be difficult to assist you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need do execute something on the UI thread after an async operation, you should simply not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in this layer. Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` and then using `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(...)` is an anti pattern in my opinion, because you turn off the automatic dispatching to the calling thread that does `await` for you.

```cs
async void SomeMethod()
{
    var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        ImObservableCollection.Add(something);
    }
}
```

If the calling thread of `SomeMethod` is not the UI thread, then you can use:

```cs
async void SomeMethod()
{
    var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => ImObservableCollection.Add(something));
    }
}
```

So this is the generic answer. Please add the error message to your question, to allow us to check for other possible error reasons.

**Note:** If `Somemethod` isn't a callback or event handler, use `Task` instead of `void` as return value. This is a best practice.

Comment: Thanks sven. Hi again, I'm allbdeveloper at xabre's ble plugin github.